# how to install ubuntu 16.04 on a PC with ubuntu 14.04 and windows7?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, uefi

I have a setup with windows7 and ubuntu14.04 in BIOS mode. When i try to install ubuntu 16.04 we get error saying that it is installing in UEFI mode.
How do we install 16.04 alongside the two OSes in BIOS mode?

Answer (score 3):

To install Ubuntu in Bios-mode you have to boot the installer in Bios-mode, also called legacy-mode. How you boot is how it installs. Choose the correct boot-option.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to boot into BIOS and disable UEFI mode all together. Disabling shouldn't really be an issue unless you are running Windows 10.